# Frequent wifi disconnects

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, realtek

I'm facing frequent WIFI disconnects and none of the suggestions I've found is working:

My Wireless info:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 01 Feb 2016 21:40 CET +0100

Booted last: 01 Feb 2016 00:00 CET +0100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.2.0-25-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:31:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, usbcore.autosuspend=-1, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Plasma

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0439]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0181 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c525 Logitech, Inc. MX Revolution Cordless Mouse
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2341:0042 Arduino SA Mega 2560 R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c328 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

rtl8192cu              69632  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        53248  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              733184  3 rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              548864  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlx48022a1761d4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlx48022a1761d4' [IF]>  
          inet addr:10.0.0.10  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'wlx48022a1761d4' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4383708 (4.3 MB)  TX bytes:578451 (578.4 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx48022a1761d4  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"2F0D38GjK"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx48022a1761d4
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx48022a1761d4
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlx48022a1761d4

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       687     1  0 21:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx48022a1761d4
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        802.11n WLAN Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rtl8192cu
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.2.0-25-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlx48022a1761d4' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.0/net/wlx48022a1761d4
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlx48022a1761d4
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     2F0D38GjK
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       9f68fe06-2be7-4e9d-8ad8-5ac14a4f3bd4
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     7 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9f68fe06-2be7-4e9d-8ad8-5ac14a4f3bd4 | 2F0D38GjK
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.0.0.10/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.0.138
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             10.0.0.138
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        host_name = C261081
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1454445426
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 10.0.0.138
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 10.0.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 10.0.0.138
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 10.0.0.10
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 10.0.0.138
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       network_number = 10.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 10.0.0.138
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'wlx48022a1761d4' [IF]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID       BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
A1-4643CF  <MAC 'A1-4643CF' [AC2]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
2F0D38GjK  <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]>  Infra  10    2457 MHz  54 Mbit/s  70      ▂▄▆_  WPA1       yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/2F0D38GjK]] (600 root)
[connection] id=2F0D38GjK | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC 'wlx48022a1761d4' [IF]> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=2F0D38GjK
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Vienna (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlx48022a1761d4  13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)

wlx48022a1761d4  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]>
                    Channel:10
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"2F0D38GjK"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000025f0f6665
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'A1-4643CF' [AC2]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"A1-4643CF"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000014c349de2142
                    Extra: Last beacon: 60ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[rtl8192cu]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n USB wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
srcversion:     730D20DBF46D54850A5E8F4
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl8192c-common,rtl_usb,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A4:10:30:FB:DF:1D:C9:62:B4:BB:7D:16:44:C3:33:7E:C4:16:DB:86
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)

[rtl_usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko
description:    USB basic driver for rtlwifi
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     E2BFFC8F9C4C5753F88B5D5
depends:        rtlwifi,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A4:10:30:FB:DF:1D:C9:62:B4:BB:7D:16:44:C3:33:7E:C4:16:DB:86
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtl8192c_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
description:    Realtek 8192C/8188C 802.11n PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Ziv Huang   <ziv_huang@realtek.com>
author:         Georgia     <georgia@realtek.com>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     1ED716BB42196D4EBC16CBE
depends:        rtlwifi
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A4:10:30:FB:DF:1D:C9:62:B4:BB:7D:16:44:C3:33:7E:C4:16:DB:86
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[rtlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
description:    Realtek 802.11n PCI wireless core
license:        GPL
author:         Larry Finger    <Larry.FInger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
author:         lizhaoming  <chaoming_li@realsil.com.cn>
srcversion:     F4CACC5FCAEBE7C22930A24
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A4:10:30:FB:DF:1D:C9:62:B4:BB:7D:16:44:C3:33:7E:C4:16:DB:86
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     065F4A11FE84275F51A59F2
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A4:10:30:FB:DF:1D:C9:62:B4:BB:7D:16:44:C3:33:7E:C4:16:DB:86
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     1F1A25B2E9C847110BD9ED9
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        A4:10:30:FB:DF:1D:C9:62:B4:BB:7D:16:44:C3:33:7E:C4:16:DB:86
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rtl8192cu]
debug: 0
swenc: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[   10.553956] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[   10.631068] rtl8192cu: MAC address: <MAC 'wlx48022a1761d4' [IF]>
[   10.631073] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   10.631315] rtl_usb: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   10.631353] rtl8192cu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
[   10.636034] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   10.638104] rtl8192cu 2-2:1.0 wlx48022a1761d4: renamed from wlan0
[   12.345224] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   12.429294] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: link down
[   12.429333] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   12.432427] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx48022a1761d4: link is not ready
[   12.434312] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   12.468694] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   12.868894] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx48022a1761d4: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   13.837948] wlx48022a1761d4: authenticate with <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]>
[   13.849121] wlx48022a1761d4: send auth to <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   13.952024] wlx48022a1761d4: send auth to <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> (try 2/3)
[   13.968588] wlx48022a1761d4: authenticated
[   13.972057] wlx48022a1761d4: associate with <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   13.976697] wlx48022a1761d4: RX AssocResp from <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[   13.978335] wlx48022a1761d4: associated
[   13.978358] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlx48022a1761d4: link becomes ready
[  733.971135] wlx48022a1761d4: deauthenticating from <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  737.836477] wlx48022a1761d4: authenticate with <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]>
[  737.859703] wlx48022a1761d4: send auth to <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  737.865289] wlx48022a1761d4: authenticated
[  737.868023] wlx48022a1761d4: associate with <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  737.877161] wlx48022a1761d4: RX AssocResp from <MAC '2F0D38GjK' [AC1]> (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[  737.878659] wlx48022a1761d4: associated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Realtek is junk. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252210/wi-fi-problems-using-asus-usb-n13-adapter/252215 As a cheap alternative get a ralink, they are so much better.

Comment: Use WPA2 only for encryption with no WEP or TKIP enabled

Comment: Changing the WPA2 encryption didn't show any effect

Answer (score 0):

Connect to internet by wire and run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
```

This will install a better driver. Test after reboot.

Comment: Getting a lot off errors: libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf line 8: ignoring bad line starting with 'option'

Comment: Your driver totally bricked my OS...

Comment: It is not my driver, but a wrong line in a config file that you added. `iwlwifi` is a completely different driver for Intel adapters. What did you add to `iwlwifi.conf`? Run `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: I have removed ifwifi.conf but the driver still bricks my OS...

Comment: What is the error now?

Comment: System is not booting as long as the wifi dongle is connected. Mentioning the driver name and giving some warnings and numbers. To much to write down because after some seconds its refreshed autom.

Comment: OK. Then remove it. There were some other drivers. You can search by `RTL8188CUS`

Comment: Will there be a Zesty release?

Comment: @cat No, there is no need for it any more.